# How can I let someone submit using the Enter key?

Tags: html, url, key, submit, enter

I made a URL shortener but it seems like whenever I try to change anything the shortener doesn't work correctly.

```
<input type="text" name="url" id="url" size="60"> <input id="submit" type="button" value="Shorten" >
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Shorten" >
```

will do the trick (notice the `type="submit"`). Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UDvvJ/), in submits the form on both button click and enter press while in text input field.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, although when you hit 'enter' nothing happens.. also it makes it so if you manually click 'Shorten' nothing happens either.

Comment: @Derek: I added a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UDvvJ/) to my answer, check it out.